# Keycloak authentication issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am trying to implement an authentication mechanism using Keycloak to my nodejs application which is running on https port 4443 (`https://localhost:4443`).

The Keycloak application is running in the EC2 instance in port 8443 https.
I am trying to login to my application which is using Keycloak for authentication which is running on port 4443.
But getting the below error:

[image]

Keycloak json file:

```
{
    "realm": "VideoKYC-Realm",
    "auth-server-url": "https://31.19.1.85:8443/auth",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "VideoKYC",
    "public-client": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Below is the settings made in the keycloak server
[image]

I dont have an SSL certificate as of now, so would need a way to bypass SSL.
Additionally I tried to run keycloack on port 8080, i was  not able to access the keycloak via browser.

However in the aws security group have allowed all the traffic as of now.

I am using the below image to run Keycloak in the EC2 instance.
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

[image]

Would request all of your help with this issue

Comment: Isn't this image is using 8080 as default port for keycloak? If you are using 8080 port then it shouldn't be giving you any issue related to certificate

Comment: Also what is the command are you using above keycloak image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

to instruct Node js to disable TLS certificate verification - https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value

Of course that is not a production setup, because it will sacrifice TLS security.

Another options (probably more complicated):

- add used CA cert to your Node JS CA certs
- maybe used keycloak lib has config to disable TLS verification on the lib level

Comment: Thanks this helped. This is for testing purpose.
Now i would need to learn how to configure SSL certificate while moving to production